# simple standalone pyqgis app gives SIGSEGV error on quit

Tags: pyqgis

I am completely new to QGIS and have just recently installed the osgeo4mac version with homebrew. I am still setting up and trying to run a very simple standalone python script.

The following script works fine:

```
from qgis.core import *

app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()

app.exitQgis()
```

The output I receive suggest that the data providers and layer registry are properly loaded and removed.

I am experiencing problems with the following script:

```
from qgis.core import *
import time

app = QgsApplication([], False)
app.initQgis()

shp_file = 'test.shp'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(shp_file, 'vlayer', 'ogr')

print layer.isValid()
for field in layer.pendingFields():
    print field.name()

app.exitQgis()

time.sleep(5)
print 'helloworld'
```

I receive confirmation that the layer is valid, and the script prints out the proper field names in my test shapefile. However, 'python quits unexpectedly' because of a  SIGSEGV error.

The last two lines are for debugging purposes and reveal what I think is a surprising behaviour. This is some of the output:

```
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:ows
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:postgres
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:spatialite
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:virtual
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [0ms] cleanup:wcs
src/core/qgsproviderregistry.cpp: 234: (clean) [1ms] cleanup:wms
helloworld
src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 36: (QgsOgrConnPool) [5015ms]Entering.
src/providers/ogr/qgsogrconnpool.cpp: 36: (QgsOgrConnPool) [0ms] Leaving.
[Finished in 7.1s with exit code -11]
```

Any Clue?

Comment: have you tried running your script from gdb (gnu debugger)? when it throws a signal like that you can get a backtrace, might give a better idea where this happened. (Never tried on a Mac though)